# Linking Error in debugging IOS app in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

here's the error

> ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for
> iOS, file
> '/Users/mohsen/Desktop/ProjectName/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps'
> for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is a snippets from the podspec file for react-native-google-maps

```
s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '3.5.0'
s.dependency 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '2.1.0'
```

I use beta version of XCode : [XCode 12](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Comment: I am having the same error only when running on an iOS Simulator release mode (Products > Scheme > Edit Scheme > then I set Release under Build Configuration for both Run and Test. However, I am not getting the error when running in release mode on a real device and in debug mode on a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Not every GoogleMaps version is supprted.

Your googlemaps framework not support arm64 architect.

Tips for solve:

1. Build phases - and try to see that you imported googlemaps framework or not.
2. If you using pod, then pod update, pod install.
3. If cordova. cordova plugins
   Remove current version, like cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googlemaps
   add to other version, like cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps@version_number

In my app the oldest version number worked correctly, and i had the same log error.